# Return Adjacent Cell Value from Max Value of Duplicates

Tags: excel

I have an excel data list of 93,000 lines (see sample below)

```
Column A - Company Name (duplicates)
Column B - Part Numbers (duplicates)
Column C - % Performance Rating for the Part Number in Column B for that Company in Column A
```

I did a pivot and created a unique excel list of Part Numbers with no duplicates. I need a formula that searches the range of 93K lines of Part Numbers and outputs the Company Name (Column A) with the highest RATING (Column C).  For example, for Part Number 1317M47G01 below it would return COMPANY C.  There might be 5,000 lines of this Part Number in the data list, I need it to search all instances that Part Number and return the Company Name with highest RATING.

```
A.Company   B.PART NUMBER C.RATING
COMPANY C   1317M47G01  86%
COMPANY F   8061-626    78%
COMPANY E   6810184M36  77%
COMPANY D   6810184M36  69%
COMPANY C   8061-626    58%
COMPANY B   6810184M36  58%
COMPANY A   1317M47G01  56%
COMPANY B   1317M47G01  47%
COMPANY A   6810184M36  45%
COMPANY C   6810184M36  45%
COMPANY B   8061-626    40%
COMPANY F   1317M47G01  35%
COMPANY A   8061-626    30%
COMPANY E   1317M47G01  30%
COMPANY F   6810184M36  29%
COMPANY D   8061-626    12%
COMPANY D   1317M47G01  12%
COMPANY E   8061-626    10%
```

Comment: What is the problem with the formula you are using now?  Please provide it along with actual and desired results.

Comment: Are the ratings sorted into descending order?

Comment: Yes, they are sorted into descending order. My issue is that when you put into a pivot table is just as messy. Need to figure out from this long list what company has the highest rating for each part number, and what that value is.

Comment: Then the first matching part number will also give the company with highest rating for that part number so it's just an index/match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$10,0))
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfect, thanks. Any idea on how I can get the corresponding rating value to display as well in Column H? Col G shows vendor with highest rating of that PN, would be nice to also display the rating value in H for that company in G.

Comment: Yes, the MATCH part of the formula would be the same but just change the INDEX part to column C so =INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$10,0))